# How to get a sorted list of filtered values of records in Odoo using filtered() function

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

How can I filter and return a sorted list from a set of records choosing which field to sort from using filter() and sort() function in Odoo?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far ? Can you share your efforts, current output and excepted output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one

```
records.filtered(lambda r: r.company_id == user.company_id).sorted(key=lambda r: r.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try using this one

```
record.filtered(lambda x: x.field_name == field_name).sorted(key=lambda r: r.field_name)
```

if no key is given function returns data in models default sort order. you refer this [link](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/online/reference/orm.html) to know more about filtered and sorted functions in Odoo.

Hope this solves your problem.